# Getting an enum associated value without the type

Tags: swift, enums, swift2

I want to add a function to my enum where it doesn't matter what `self` is, but just does an operation on the associated values.

```
enum ProblemType: CustomStringConvertible {
    case Addition(left: Int, right: Int)
    case Subtraction(left: Int, right: Int)
    case Division(left: Int, right: Int)
    case Multiplication(left: Int, right: Int)

    func doSomething() {
        let left, right = self(left, right) // obviously wrong
    }
}
```

I know the associated values can be different between types, but is this possible to do when all the types are the same?

Comment: Sounds like you really want `enum BinaryProblemType { case Addition, Subtraction, Division, Multiplication }; struct BinaryProblem { let type: BinaryProblemType, left: Int, right: Int }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you just have to handle all the cases. But this is easily done with a utility method:

```
enum ProblemType {
    case Addition(left: Int, right: Int)
    case Subtraction(left: Int, right: Int)
    case Division(left: Int, right: Int)
    case Multiplication(left: Int, right: Int)
    func leftAndRight() -> (Int,Int) {
        switch self {
        case Addition(let l, let r): return (l,r)
        case Subtraction(let l, let r): return (l,r)
        case Division(let l, let r): return (l,r)
        case Multiplication(let l, let r): return (l,r)
        }
    }
    func doSomething() {
        let (left, right) = self.leftAndRight()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Associated types are meant to be attached to a specific case so there is no easy way to do that. That said, it isn't difficult to manually add that functionality.

```
enum ProblemType: CustomStringConvertible {
    case Addition(left: Int, right: Int)
    case Subtraction(left: Int, right: Int)
    case Division(left: Int, right: Int)
    case Multiplication(left: Int, right: Int)

    var unwrapProblemType: (left: Int, right: Int) {
        let result: (Int, Int)
        switch self {
        case .Addition(left: let l, right: let r):
            result = (l, r)
        case .Subtraction(left: let l, right: let r):
            result = (l, r)
        case .Division(left: let l, right: let r):
            result = (l, r)
        case .Multiplication(left: let l, right: let r):
            result = (l, r)
        }
        return result
    }

    var description: String {
        let (left, right) = self.unwrapProblemType
        return "Left: \(left); Right: \(right)"
    }
}
```

Side Note: If you are repeating all of that left/right information it might be better to use a class, struct or protocol instead of a enum.